# Monkey patch external CSS

Tags: javascript, css

This is generic question, is it possible to monkey patch the CSS from link tag? I want to modify PrismJS library that have `color` and `background` and patch it to have `--color` and `--background`. Is something like this possible dynamically using JavaScript?

I would like this to be generic so no Service Worker, that will work only for local files that can be changed by modifying the file, I want to affect every possible url the same I'm patching JavaScript file. I can assume that the CSS selectors will always be the same.

The problem is that without the monkey patch I will need to maintain all themes that PrismJS have for different colors, I can write script that will create those styles for me but I want to know if there is a way to monkey patch. Also I can have single CSS file to be used instead of the PrismJS CSS, but I will lose different styles.

I have other options but right now I only want to know if monkey patch of external CSS is possible? I can't find anything like this.

I need to add that PrismJS themes are pretty simple they are just few selectors with colors. I'm not sure if they all have same selectors though.

**EDIT:**

To give you context I need this for jQuery Terminal to render text that user type (any programming language to be in color). I have one CSS that I have locally but without that file it don't work exactly the same (mainly there is lack of style for text selection that I would like to be in color, to have 100% working code as I want). The idea is to use same monkey patch I have but to use prism.css.

Comment: It seems like the simple solution is since you are assuming the selectors are all the same, that you could just write the javascript targeting those selectors and instead of using `--color` just use a variable in javascript to change the color.

Comment: @imvain2 text is dynamic it can change in any time it make no sens to change it in JavaScript using selecters and have more then one color I don't know what are the colors and what is the text, I need this for library that render any text.